# Any particular function to initialize GPU other than the first cudaMalloc call?

Tags: cuda, gpu

The first cudaMalloc call is slow (like 0.2 sec) because of some initialization work on GPU. Is there any function that solely do initialization, so that I can separate the time? cudaSetDevice seems to reduce the time to 0.15 secs, but still does not eliminate all init overheads.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A call to

```
cudaFree(0);
```

is the canonical way to force lazy context establishment in the CUDA runtime. You can't reduce the overhead, that is a function of driver, runtime and operating system latencies. But the call above will let you control how/when those overheads occur during program execution.

**EDIT in 2015** to add that the heuristics of context initialisation in the runtime API have subtly changed over time so that `cudaSetDevice` now establishes a context, so the `cudaFree()` call isn't explicitly required to intialise a context, you can use `cudaSetDevice`instead. Also note that some set-up time will still be incurred at the first kernel launch, whereas before this wasn't the case. For for kernel timing, it is best to include a warm-up call first before launching the kernel you will time to remove this set-up latency. It appears that the various profiling tools have enough granularity built in to avoid this without any extra API calls or kernel calls.

Comment: Exactly! It captures all initialization time! Thanks!