# Why is the first cudaMalloc the only bottleneck?

Tags: cuda

I defined this function :

```
void cuda_entering_function(...)
{
    StructA *host_input, *dev_input;
    StructB *host_output, *dev_output;

    host_input = (StructA*)malloc(sizeof(StructA));
    host_output = (StructB*)malloc(sizeof(StructB));
    cudaMalloc(&dev_input, sizeof(StructA));
    cudaMalloc(&dev_output, sizeof(StructB));

    ... some more other cudaMalloc()s and cudaMemcpy()s ...

    cudaKernel<< ... >>(dev_input, dev_output);

    ...
}
```

This function is called several times (about 5 ~ 15 times) throughout my program, and I measured this program's performance using `gettimeofday()`.

Then I found that the bottleneck of `cuda_entering_function()` is the first `cudaMalloc()` - the very first `cudaMalloc()` throughout my whole program. Over 95% of the total execution time of `cuda_entering_function()` was consumed by the first `cudaMalloc()`, and this also happens when I changed the size of first `cudaMalloc()`'s allocating memory or when I changed the executing order of `cudaMalloc()`s.

What is the reason and is there any way to reduce the first cuda allocating time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first `cudaMalloc` is responsible for the initialization of the device too, because it's the **first call to any function involving the device**. This is why you take such a hit: it's overhead due to the use of CUDA and your GPU. You should make sure that your application can gain a sufficient speedup to compensate for the overhead.

In general, people use a call to an initialization function in order to setup their device. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166799/any-particular-function-to-initialize-gpu-other-than-the-first-cudamalloc-call) answer, you can see that apparently a call to `cudaFree(0)` is the canonical way to do so. [This sample](http://www.evl.uic.edu/sjames/cs525/apps/sample.cu) shows the use of cudaSetDevice, which could be a good habit if you ever work on machines with several CUDA-ready devices.