# cudaGetCacheConfig takes 0.5 seconds - how/why?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I'm using CUDA 8.0 on a Xeon-based system with a GTX Titan X (GM 200). It works fine, but - I get long overheads compared to my weak GTX 600 series card at home. Specifically, when I timeline I find that a call to `cudaGetCacheConfig()` is consistently taking the CUDA runtime API an incredible amount of time: 530-560 msec, or over 0.5 seconds. This, while other calls don't take as much. For example, `cuDeviceGetTotalMem` takes 0.7 msec (also quite a bit of time, but an order of magnitude less), and `cuDeviceGetAttribute` (which is probably limited to host-side code only) takes 0.031 msec.

Why is this happening? Or rather - how could that be possible? And can I do anything to ameliorate this situation?

**Notes:**

- The `cudaGetCacheConfig()` gets called after `cudaGetDeviceCount()`, but probably (not 100% certain) not before any other runtime API calls.
- If I prepend a `cudaGetDeviceProperties()` call before the `cudaGetCacheConfig()` call, the former takes ~0.6 msec and the latter still takes over 0.5 sec (581 msec in my last measurement).

Comment: Is `cudaGetCacheConfig` the first cuda runtime API call in the program that you are timing?

Comment: @RobertCrovella: No, see edit.

Comment: If its early enough in your program, it may still be absorbing some of the CUDA lazy initialization overhead.  Try putting a `cudaGetCacheConfig()` somewhere near the end of your code after a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` call, and see if the profiler reported time is much shorter for it.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: A second call immediately following the first one takes 1.574 usec. A third call at the end of the program doesn't seem to show up on the timeline somehow.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: But, still - 0.5 seconds of startup overhead? What is it doing, writing a novel?

Comment: CUDA can have pretty long start up overheads.  These will vary by machine configuration e.g. number of GPUs, and size of system memory can affect start up overhead.  If that is what is happening here there are many questions like yours here on the `cuda` tag.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Fair enough. And that question is helpful (though somewhat frustrating).

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: CUDA lazy initialization (as @RobertCrovella suggests).**

@RobertCrovella explains in the [dupe bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404220/slowness-of-first-cudamalloc-k40-vs-k20-even-after-cudasetdevice):

> CUDA initialization usually includes establishment of UVM, which involves harmonizing of device and host memory maps. If your server has more system memory than your PC, it is one possible explanation for the disparity in initialization time. The OS may have an effect as well, finally the memory size of the GPU may have an effect.

the machine on which I get this behavior has 256 GB of memory, 32 times more than my home machine; and the GPU itself has 12 GB, 4 times more than the GPU on my home machine. This means I can - unfortunately - expect much longer initialization of the CUDA driver and/or runtime API than on my home machine. Some or all of this initialization is performed *in a lazy fashion*, which in my case happens to be when `cudaGetCacheConfig()` is called; I suppose the other calls only require some of the initialization (not clear why, though).