# How do I mitigate CUDA's very long initialization delay?

Tags: optimization, cuda, initialization, delay, unified-memory

Initializing CUDA in a newly-created process can take quite some time [as long as a half-second](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42162337/1593077) or more on many server-grade machines of today. As @RobertCrovella [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404220/slowness-of-first-cudamalloc-k40-vs-k20-even-after-cudasetdevice), CUDA initialization usually includes establishment of a Unified Memory model, which involves harmonizing of device and host memory maps. This can take quite a long time for machines with a lot of memory; and there might be other factors contributing to this long delay.

This effect becomes quite annoying when you want to run a sequence of CUDA-utilizing processes, which do not use complicated virtual memory mappings: They each have to wait their their long wait - despite the fact that "essentially", they could just re-use whether initializations CUDA made the last time (perhaps with a bit of cleanup code).

Now, obviously, if you somehow rewrote the code for all those processes to execute within a single process - that would save you those long initialization costs. But isn't there a simpler approach? What about:

- Passing the same state information / CUDA context between processes?
- Telling CUDA to ignore most host memory altogether?
- Making the Unified Memory harmonization more lazy than it is now, so that it only happens to the extent that it's actually necessary?
- Starting CUDA with Unified Memory disabled?
- Keeping some daemon process on the side and latching on to it's already-initialized CUDA state?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about already exists. It is called MPS (MULTI-PROCESS SERVICE), and it basically keeps a single GPU context alive at all times with a daemon process that emulates the driver API. The initial target application is MPI, but it does bascially what you envisage.

Read more here:

https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/pdf/CUDA_Multi_Process_Service_Overview.pdf

http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2015/presentation/S5584-Priyanka-Sah.pdf

Comment: Hmm, sounds kind of heavy-weight and overhead-laden. and I don't want to do IPC all the time... but is that FOSS? Perhaps one could only take the lower layers of that and hack together a simpler alternative.

Comment: It is a NVIDIA provided codebase. I would expect it is closed source.

Comment: MPS is closed source.  Another method that may offer some mitigation in some scenarios for machines that have multiple GPUs is to restrict the CUDA runtime to only use the necessary GPUs, via the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` [environment variable](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars).  This can be specified per-process.  This methodology may also offer some benefits in certain pre-Pascal UM scenarios.

Comment: I wonder whether *users* putting pressure on OS developers to speed up the relevant OS calls used for setting up the memory mappings needed for UVM would help? Obviously not a short-term solution for individual users.

Comment: This tool seems to be Linux-only. How to alleviate the problem of CUDA initialization on Windows?