# cufftPlan2d exception spend a long time to execute

Tags: cuda

I am working with the cufft library. I am using the cufftPlan2d function to create the plan I need. The following is my code:

```
cudaEvent_t start1,stop1;
    cudaEventCreate(&start1);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop1);
    cudaEventRecord(start1, 0);

    cufftHandle plan1;
    cufftPlan2d(&plan1,HEIGHT2,WIDTH2,CUFFT_C2C);
    cudaEventRecord(stop1,0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop1);
    float etime;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&etime,start1,stop1);
```

where HEIGHT2=1080*2,WIDTH2=1920*2. but etime=919.542419ms,it take too long ,what can I do to reduce the time?

Comment: I presume you are actually asking about the *first* time you call `cufftPlan2d`?

Comment: @talonmies :actually,I have called a kernel before calling cufftPlan2d. Like this :lut_kernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(a,b,c);when lut_kernel is done, cufftPlan2d(&plan1,HEIGHT2,WIDTH2,CUFFT_C2C) is executed

Comment: But is is the *first* `cufftPlan2d` call?

Comment: @talonmies:yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you call a cuda command a lot of initialization will take place. This is due to the fact that cuda uses lazy initialization, see talonmies previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166799/any-particular-function-to-initialize-gpu-other-than-the-first-cudamalloc-call) on how to catch it.

Citing from [Nvidia forums](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/914806/gpu-accelerated-libraries/the-initialization-of-cufft-/post/4802912/#4802912):

> CUDA uses lazy initialization. If you want to be sure that all necessary initialization is complete for function xyz, the only way to be sure is to call function xyz. After that, if you call xyz again, there should be no initialization overhead.
>
> For CUDA, a substantial amount of initialization should be complete after the first call to a device memory allocator such as cudaMalloc.
>
> For a library like CUFFT, a substantial amount of the initialization should be complete after calling any library function that invokes a device kernel (such as any cufft exec call).

Comment: Well, yes that is *why* (but note that the answer you linked to is out of date and even the "correct, modern" way to manage context initialisation won't greatly effect the behaviour being asked about). But what about the question about *what to do* about the long initialization time on first call?

Comment: "You can't reduce the overhead, that is a function of driver, runtime and operating system latencies." Is from your old post, should I add this to my post?

Comment: creating a cufft plan does things which are independent of CUDA context initialisation and which take time. The source of the delay isn't context establishment